# This is a mini game that I want to add to my webpage but i cant find out whats going wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure what's wrong. The javascript code isn't working on my html webpage. I am new to Javascript so I would really appreciate some help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="/slider.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" context="width=device-width, initial-scale=10"/>

  <style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style> 
</head>
```

So I think this area is the area I messed up on, I'm not sure.

```
     <body onload="startGame()">
       <script>

        var myGamePiece;
        var myObstacles = [];
        var myScore;

    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
        myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
        myScore = new component("30px", "Conslas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
        my GameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea,20);
        },
        Clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.score = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.gravity = 0;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
                ctx.font= this.width + " " + this.height;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
            this.hitBottom();
        }
        this.hitBottom = function() {
            var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
            if (this.y > rockbottom) {
                this.y = rockbottom;
                this.gravitySpeed = 0;
            }
        }
        this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
                crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
        }
    }
    function updateGameArea() {
        var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
        for (i = 0, i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                return;
            }
        }               
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            minHeight = 20;
            maxHeight = 200;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
            minGap = 50;
            maxGap = 200;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
                myObstacles[i].x += -1;
                myObstacles[i].update();
            }
        myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
        return false;
    }
    function accelerate(n) {
        myGamePiece.gravity = n;
    }
    </script>
  <br>
        <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)"
        onmouseup="accelerate(0.5)">ACCELERATE<button>
        <p>In order to stay in the air use the ACCELERATE button</p>
        <p>HOW LONG CAN YOU STAY ALIVE?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any useful output in the **developer** tools console that may indicate an error in your code perhaps?

Comment: e.g `my GameArea.start();` syntax error, `var otherleft otherobj.x;` another one, `for (i = 0, i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {` that `,` should be a `;` ... there's possibly a few more, like 7 missing `;` - which may or may not be a problem

Comment: this `if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}` is an *interesting* piece of code - seems it can be re-written `if ((myGameArea.frameNo % n) == 0) {return true;}` - but better still, that function is just `function everyinterval(n) {
        return !(myGameArea.frameNo % n);
    }`

Comment: Create the demo for this. JSFiddle or codepen. And like @JaromandaX said, check the output in developer tools.

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. Debug the code, look for errors and try to isolate the area where the issue is occurring. Describe the desired behaviour vs what happens now.

Answer (score 2):

You have several syntax errors.

`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement   index.html:26:11`
Change `my GameArea.start();` to `myGameArea.start();`

`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement   index.html:84:26`
Change `var otherleft otherobj.x;` to `var otherleft = otherobj.x;`

`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement   index.html:97:50`
Change `for (i = 0, i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {` to `for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {`

`TypeError: myGameArea.clear is not a function   index.html:102:9`
Change `myGameArea.clear();` to `myGameArea.Clear();`

After those fixes I was able to run your game.
[image]

In the future use Console tool of your web browser(<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in FF). You are also encouraged to use other Development Tools that modern web browsers have to offer.

More reading on Web Console of FF can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console). Though, all major browsers have their equivalents and they don't even differ that much nowadays.